# Function with completion handler, when does execution finish?

Tags: ios, swift

Say I have the following function definition:

```
func validResponse(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?, viewController: UIViewController, context: String?, withCompletion completion: @escaping (Bool?, String?) -> ()) {
```

Then inside this function I have:

```
case 500: //internal server error
    debug.log(tag: "NetworkHelper", content: "\(response!.url!.path) returned 500. Payload: \(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)")

    completion(true, "500, internal server error")

    print("do something")
```

will the `print("do something")` get executed? I dont want it to, but want to know if I should be including a `return` after all my completion calls?

EDIT: Say I have a bunch of code like this:

```
if data == nil {
    debug.log(tag: "NetworkHelper", content: "Error, did not receive any data on \(response!.url!.path)")
    completion(false, "No data was received from the server")
}

if error != nil {
    debug.log(tag: "NetworkHelper", content: "Error, calling GET on \(response!.url!.path)")
    debug.log(tag: "NetworkHelper", content: error!.localizedDescription)
    completion(false, genericError)
}
```

Do I need to call return after each `completion` call?

Comment: Yes, it will be executed. Better to remove it than to leave unreachable code

Comment: @CodeDifferent see edit. So I need to include `return` after each `completion` call?

Comment: Yes, since you don't want to execute the subsequent code. `guard` is a more Swifty solution since it forces you to return from the completion block

Comment: @CodeDifferent ok thanks. Feel free to post this as the answer, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completion is just function. If you want to execute something after calling this function, you will just add this code after completion calling. If you do not want to call any code after completion, just do not write this code.

And you should use *guard* for checking nil case:

```
guard let data = data else { return } 
debug.log(tag: "NetworkHelper", content: "Error, did not receive any data on \(response!.url!.path)")
        completion(false, "No data was received from the server")
```